# Weblogic deployment error

Tags: java, weblogic, myeclipse

I have weblogic 9.2 and myeclipse6.0.1.I am able to deploy the project through myeclipse, but not able to see in the weblogic console(inside the deployments).

project deploying and running the server in myeclipse.as well project able to see in the weblogic domain autodeploy folder.But inside the weblogic console nothing there.

What is the problem here ?

Comment: As you say "project able to see in the weblogic domain autodeploy folder" - is that in the WLS which is configured in MyEclipse or the external 9.2 which you have? Or are both the same?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with glassfish a while back. Your issue may be that myEclipse has defined its own weblogic app-server and is not using the one you have on your machine. To change the settings and set your default weblogic server go to Window->Preferences->MyEclipse->Servers->WebLogic->WebLogic9.x and specify your installation directory and any other settings you require.

Comment: Are you running it using the new settings? If you right click on your Java project and select Run As -> Run Configurations... is it using the MyEclipse Server application, and if so is it specifying the correct server that you had previously edited?